# Mysql looping error code #1064 inside stored procedure [revised]

Tags: mysql, while-loop, syntax-error

I edited this question cause the answers below mentioned that when using while and begin, it should be inside a stored procedure.

So now I'm running this inside a stored procedure but I'm still getting an error.

```
counter;
while counter < 2
begin
GOTO counter

SELECT var1 AS LOCATION,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.tagid = var2 THEN t2.floatvalue ELSE 0 END), 2) AS MR
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.tagid = var3 THEN t2.floatvalue ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Flw,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.tagid = var4 THEN t2.floatvalue ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Prs,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.tagid = var5 THEN t2.floatvalue ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Lvl
FROM table2 t2

INNER JOIN table1  t1
  ON t1.id = t2.tagid

WHERE t2.t_stamp = (SELECT MAX(t2.t_stamp) 
                    FROM table2  t2 
                    WHERE t1.id = t2.tagid)
counter = counter+1
end

1:
var1
var2
var3
var4
var5

2:
var1
var2
var3
var4
var5
```

This is the error I'm getting

`MySQL said: #1064 -You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin GOTO counter SELECT var1 AS LOCATION, ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.tagid' at line 2`

And I didn't include the `CREATE PROCEDURE` cause I saw a post wherein it was easier to just go to the `ROUTINES` panel and paste the SQL Query without the CREATE, DELIMITER... etc.
How should I fix this error?

Comment: How are you executing this code?

Comment: what do you mean? on phpmyadmin
i'm trying to provide the sqlfiddle link but i think its down right now

Comment: I mean are you trying to execute it as a sql batch or it's a part of a stored routine? If it's a former you can do this in MySQL. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Control flow statements (`WHILE`, `IF`, etc) in MySQL can be used **only** in a context of a stored routine (procedure, function, trigger, event). You can't use them on their own in a SQL batch.

> **[Flow Control Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flow-control-statements.html)**
>   MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control **within stored programs**.

Comment: I have visited the URL you have specified in your answer but i didn't find anything on that page relevant to the answer you have mentioned above. Can you please point me to official documentation that advocates your statement?

Comment: It's actually the very first words written on that page "MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within stored programs."

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand Exactly. Thanks for the citation.

Comment: @peterm I edited my question and now the code is inside a stored procedure but I'm still getting an error